# Reason why 2nd AuthenticationProvider is called

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have the following `WebSecurityConfig` of Spring Security in my Spring Boot application.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class Form1LoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .antMatcher("/uid/serverinfo.html")
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admins/login")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/uid/serverinfo.html")
                .authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/admins/login")
                .loginPage("/admins/login")
                .failureUrl("/admins/login?error")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/uid/serverinfo.html");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        }

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
            return new LDAPAuthenticationProvider();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class Form2LoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .antMatcher("/admins/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admins/login")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admins/**")
                .authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/admins/login")
                .loginPage("/admins/login")
                .failureUrl("/admins/login?error")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admins/main");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        }

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
            return new RDBAuthenticationProvider();
        }
    }
}
```

If accessing to `http:localhost:8080/admins/main`, my expected result is `RDBAuthenticationProvider.authenticate()` is called, but `LDAPAuthenticationProvider.authenticate()` is actually called.

Does anyone know the reason and how to fix?

Comment: Check this for using multiple AuthenticationProviders: http://phuonghuynh.github.io/java/spring/security/2015/09/06/spring-security-multiple-authentication-providers.html

Comment: I want to protect access to /admins/* (by DB) and /uid/serverinfo.html (by LDAP) but ...